# Firebase Messaging service worker on chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement FCM chrome client on Eclipse IDE.

Using Javascript, I am trying to register the default service worker : firebase-messaging-sw.js but the path for this js file cannot be resolved by project.

The SDK is searching for this file at hosting level: /firebase-messaging-sw.js i.e. https://localhost:8080/firebase-messaging-sw.js but not at https://localhost:8080/myapp/firebase-messaging-sw.js

Therefore, I get Error :
Firebase Service worker not found while using GWT (404 Error)

How can I resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Service workers by default should reside on the root of the application. To register a service worker st some other location than the default location, you can use the following code.

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw-test/sw.js', {scope: '/sw-test/'})
  .then(function(reg) {
    // registration worked
    console.log('Registration succeeded. Scope is ' + reg.scope);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    // registration failed
    console.log('Registration failed with ' + error);
  });
}
```

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers),

> 1. The outer block performs a feature detection test to make sure service workers are supported before trying to register one.
> 2. Next, we use the ServiceWorkerContainer.register() function to register the service worker for this site, which is just a JavaScript
>      file residing inside our app (note this is the file's URL relative to
>      the origin, not the JS file that references it.)
> 3. The scope parameter is optional, and can be used to specify the subset of your content that you want the service worker to control. In
>      this case, we have specified '/sw-test/', which means all content
>      under the app's origin. If you leave it out, it will default to this
>      value anyway, but we specified it here for illustration purposes.
> 4. The .then() promise function is used to chain a success case onto our promise structure.  When the promise resolves successfully, the
>      code inside it executes.
> 5. Finally, we chain a .catch() function onto the end that will run if the promise is rejected.
>
> This registers a service worker, which runs in a worker context, and
>   therefore has no DOM access. You then run code in the service worker
>   outside of your normal pages to control their loading.